# pytesseract image_to_string is performing slow in multi-threaded environment

Tags: string, image, python-tesseract

I am using pytesseract library to convert scanned pdf to text. This works fine only  when pdfs are individually sent through pytesseract's image_to_string function. It is working fine.

The problem occurs is when I send pdfs back to back without any delay in multi-threaded environment. I am observing pytesseract is performing very slow in this situation

My question is : Does anyone faced similar issue and rectified it ? what was the fix ? or Do I need to follow different code design pattern while using this library ? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Here I m passing one pdf document which contains multiple scanned pdf pages

Comment: @KJ  For example in my case I am sending 10 pdf docs with 10-15 pages at a time back to back for pytessreact api. For each document seperate thread is created. Do you think single instance of pytessreact is performing all 10 threads work

Comment: Is it possible to create multiple instances of pytessreact and get results from them parallelly ? Do you have any examples on how to create multiple instances of pytessreact?

Comment: Sure @KJ I will try out with single thread and check if there is any improvment in performance and can I set this OMP_THREAD_LIMIT=1 in dockerised python application.

Comment: Adding OMP_THREAD_LIMIT=1 has improved performance in multi thread environment but some times I see scanned pdfs get stuck inside image_to_string function and hangs up. It doesn't see control coming out of it. What could be the issue causing this hang